# Memory available calls to VeriFone library

Tags: c, memory-management, out-of-memory, posix, verifone

Have any developers seen inconsistency in the results of memory calls to VeriFone library functions in svc_swi.h for Evo range?
We have old code that seemed fine for Verix/VerixV.  But for a newer unit (these have very much larger memory than the predecessor HW) these results appeared in our monitoring:-

> Total RAM:    65536k  Total Flash:    131072k Available
>   RAM:  114654k Available Flash:    114650k

The code to get these stats is unchanged since we added Evo to our stable.

```
long GetFileSysAvail(const char *drive) const
{
    fs_size fs;

    fs.Avail = 0;
#ifdef __arm
    (void)dir_get_sizes(drive, &fs);
#else
    dir_get_sizes((char *)drive, &fs);
#endif

    return fs.Avail;
}
```

Comment: Keep us posted on what you find--I'm curious to know, myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I'll hazard a guess--In Verix and VerixV terminals (such as the 3740/3750 and the 510/570), there was both *Flash* **AND** *RAM* and you specified which "drive" you wanted by indicating `I:` or `F:` before your file name.  In the 520 (and I suspect other eVo terminals, but I'm not sure) there is no (non-volatile) RAM and so even if you specify `I:`, you are still storing to FLASH memory.

If you look at the documentation for `dir_get_sizes`, you'll notice that what is written up in the `Verix V` version is different than what is written up in the `eVo` one.  The primary difference that really stands out to me is the note:

> I: and F: are both on the Nand flash, the “Avail” member of the
>   resulting struct fs_sizes tells the total (I: + F:) available NAND
>   flash memory at the time the function is called.

This is all well and good and *could* explain why "Available" is higher than "Total", especially since you are using a different API to get the total size (I'm assuming SVC_RAM_SIZE and SVC_FLASH_SIZE) which may be making some sort of a distinction between `I:` and `F:`.  If this were the case, then it would imply that you are using just about 81954k of the available storage space. ...Except for one nagging problem: the "Available RAM" is 4k higher than "Available Flash" and we would expect them to be identical.  That I can't explain unless you are allocating and/or storing bunch of other things between calls...?

Another significant difference is the fact that, while both return an `int`, the Verix V version only indicates that -1 is returned on failure (implying, but not explicitly stating that 0 is returned on success) with errno set to either `ENOENT` or `EACCES`.  On the other hand, the eVo version states that the return value is "The available memory in bytes."  It may be interesting to compare the value that is returned from `dir_get_sizes` with the one set in `fs.Avail`.

Comment: Thanks @PhatWrat for that useful feedback.  Yes, you are correct, we do use SVC_RAM_SIZE.  So, I will tinker around and let you know if I get further along.

Comment: Hi @PhatWrat, I ran a memory report for comparison, from the System Mode Menu option
4> Memory Usage
The result agrees with your above comment on RAM and Flash in Evo units.
So the RAM reported by the lib API call must be garnered via a different call than the one used for the attached memory report?